# How to make a really SMALL font size in a Visual Basic 6 PictureBox?

Tags: vb6, fonts, picturebox, font-size

I am trying to print words of varying font sizes in a PictureBox.

I've done `pb.FontSize = 5, pb.FontSize = 10, and pb.FontSize = 15`, all the way up to `pb.FontSize = 30` when printing out a word (using `pb.Print "XYZ"`).

However, the font size of 1 through 5 looks exactly like 10.  Font sizes of 20 and greater clearly get bigger and bigger.

Is there a minimum font size in a VB6 PictureBox?  I want font sizes that are smaller than 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the "Small fonts" font.
Not all fonts can scale properly, and of those that can, may not be readable at small sizes.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response.  I just found out that the font type is MS Sans Serif, the default font as you said MarkJ.  What is a font that you would suggest that I use?

Comment: "Microsoft Sans Serif" and "MS Sans Serif" are different, the first is true type, the other isn't. The recomended font is different depending on the version of Windows, but setting it (in code) to "Ms Shell Dlg" should get the default.

Comment: Hi Deanna, thanks for your response!  I am using Windows 7.  Given that, what font would you recommend.  I see that Ms Shell Dlg would work, but I am just curious what Win7's recommended font would be in my situation.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: A quick [Google for `windows 7 font guidelines`](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=windows+7+font+guidelines&meta=) gives you the [Windows UX guidelines on fonts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511282.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Are you using a [TrueType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType) font, which can be scaled to any size?

Fixed-size fonts only support a limited set of fonts. The default font in Vb6 is fixed-size (Microsoft Sans Serif).